# InvalidRequestException(why:Unknown identifier

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-storm, kundera

when I tried to save a table to **cassandra** using **persist()** method and **kundera** framework, i receive the error:

```
28462 [Thread-15-localhostAMQPbolt0-executor[2 2]] INFO  d.d.pieceDAOImpl - start to insert data
28513 [Thread-15-localhostAMQPbolt0-executor[2 2]] INFO  c.i.c.c.CassandraClientBase - Returning cql query  INSERT INTO "pieces"("width","height","depth","IdPiece") VALUES(10.0,11.0,12.0,'1') .
28543 [Thread-15-localhostAMQPbolt0-executor[2 2]] ERROR c.i.c.c.CassandraClientBase - Error while executing query  INSERT INTO "pieces"("width","height","depth","IdPiece") VALUES(10.0,11.0,12.0,'1')
28544 [Thread-15-localhostAMQPbolt0-executor[2 2]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: InvalidRequestException(why:Unknown identifier IdPiece)
        at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:448) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:414) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:73) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__8226$fn__8239$fn__8292.invoke(executor.clj:851) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__554.invoke(util.clj:484) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_99]
Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: InvalidRequestException(why:Unknown identifier IdPiece)
        at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:180) ~[project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at database.dao.pieceDAOImpl.insert(pieceDAOImpl.java:54) ~[project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at database.controller.DatabaseController.saveSensorEntitie(DatabaseController.java:47) ~[project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at connector.bolt.PrinterBolt.execute(PrinterBolt.java:66) ~[project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__8226$tuple_action_fn__8228.invoke(executor.clj:731) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__8147.invoke(executor.clj:463) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__7663.onEvent(disruptor.clj:40) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:435) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        ... 6 more
```

And im sur that my idpiece is the primary key of my table.

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.pieces (
    idpiece text PRIMARY KEY,
    depth double,
    height double,
    width double
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

my class entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pieces", schema = "mykeyspace@cassandra_pu")
public class PieceEntitie implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private String IdPiece;
    @Column
    private double width;
    @Column
    private double height;
    @Column
    private double depth;
```

how can i resolve this problem ?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cassandra [quoted identifiers are case-sensitive](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#identifiers).

So your column name `"IdPiece"` is different then actual column `idpiece` in your table `pieces`

Answer (score 1):

Kundera uses quoted identifiers in the generated query.

`INSERT INTO "pieces"("width","height","depth","IdPiece") VALUES(10.0,11.0,12.0,'1')`

In cassandra, quoted identifiers are **case-sensitive**. So there is no such column "IdPiece" in your table.

Solution is to rename your field to `idpiece` in entity class